# Craft Commerce update variant field in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, elementcriteriamodel, php

I'm trying to get, update, and save products &/or variants in my plugin controller, and am stuck on accessing/changing/saving updated fields.

```
// get product ID from post
$variant_id = craft()->request->getPost('variant_id');

// create criteria
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Commerce_Variant');
$criteria->id = $variant_id;

// query
$variant = $criteria->first();
```

The above works just fine and gets the variant. But now I need to update a few fields and save it. Any idea how to do this?

```
$variant->getContent()->myCustomField = 'new value';
```

How would I then save `$variant`?

Comment: More proper answer now below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the general mechanism for updating custom fields on elements - use `setContentFromPost` and then call the element's save function.

```
    $variant->setContentFromPost(array(
        'fieldHandle' => $newValue,
    ));
    craft()->commerce_variants->saveVariant($variant);
```

You should catch exceptions around that really, to handle any errors that may arise (as the model gets validated during save etc.)

Comment: I'm running into the same type of error I keep getting for trying to access fields etc. In this case it is: 'Call to a member function setContentFromPost() on a non-object' Am I going about retrieving the variant models the wrong way for it to not be returning an object?

Comment: Oops, I was getting an array returned through ->find(), changed to ->first(). Now your suggestion works! I'll be sure to catch exceptions. Super appreciate the help Jeremy.

Comment: No worries.  Hoping you're going to build us all a totally sweet product editing system!